# Python: 3D grid from JSON data

Tags: python, json, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have been struggling with a Python related problem (or challenge) for quite some time now. And now I believe I should get some help or hints from you folks.

In the [attached file](https://aarhusvand-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/anl_aarhusvand_dk/ESEC8xbP2OJCpLobZTRcGt8B09b_GpHzxcRJU2na1rAaJg?e=CVa0Tt) you will find a JSON file object with the data I'm working with. I'm loading in the data using the following lines of code:

```py
with open('json_data.json','r') as openfile:
    json_object = json.load(openfile)
```

Now, when looking into `json_object`, you will notice a lot of relevant information, such as the number of cells in a 2D dimension, `Numx` and `Numy`. Now, the key/parameter I am interested in is the `data` key, i.e. `json_object['data']`. This parameter, which is a list item, holds `Numx` by `Numy` dictionary instances, holding X and Y coordinates for each. Each instance also holds the 3rd dimension, the time dimension in the key `Data`, which is a list item, holding n timesteps of values. It may be obvious, but I feel I should mention that the timestamps are the same for each coordinate instance.

So, to summarize, for each coordinate, there is a timeseries with values, which I would like to convert into a 3D dimensional grid using `numpy`. How would I do that?

I've tried to convert the `data` key into a Pandas DataFrame with this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json_object["data"], record_path =["Data"],meta=["X","Y"])
```

This gives me a DataFrame with values corresponding to the given timestep and coordinate.
But then I don't know how to continue - how do I turn this into a 3D grid?

Then I tried to loop over each timestamp, so I would have n timesteps of 2D grids. But then I struggle how to implement the time in order to make it 3-dimensional.

```
timeStamps = [t['Time'] for t in data_json['data'][0]['Data']]
dfTimestamps = {}
for i,ts in enumerate(timeStamps):
   dfTimestamps[ts] = {}
   X = []
   Y = []
   vals = []
   for d in data_json['data']:
      X.append(d['X'])
      Y.append(d['Y'])
      vals.append(d['Data'][i]['Value'])
      dfTimestamps[ts]['X'] = X
      dfTimestamps[ts]['Y'] = Y
      dfTimestamps[ts]['Value'] = vals
```

EDIT:
I will try to write som example data from the JSON fileobject below.

```
{'info': {'Parameters': None,
  'Unit': 'mm/hour',
  'Location': 'Input geojson',
  'Point': {'IdPoints': 0,
   'Name': None,
   'Description': None,
   'X': 571125,
   'Y': 6225625,
   'EPSG': None,
   'Latitude': 0,
   'Longitude': 0,
   'CreatedDatetime': '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
   'OrganizationId': None,
   'ResponsibleUserId': None,
   'Id': 0},
  'PointId': None,
  'ParameterId': 'Rainintensity, id: 204',
  'Timezone': 'UTC',
  'DataSource': 'X-band Sabro, RadarId: {303}',
  'EPSG': '32632',
  'CreatedDateTime': '2023-07-13T13:55:18.9099301Z',
  'AllPoints': False,
  'dxdy': 250,
  'Numx': 7,
  'Numy': 6,
  'X0': 0,
  'Y0': 0,
  'MissingSteps': 0,
  'ProcessQuality': [{'qualityIndex': 0,
   'qualityDescription': 'No problem detected',
   'qualitySteps': 3241,
   'missingSteps': None,
   'fromUTC': '2023-07-10T00:00:00',
   'toUTC': '2023-07-12T06:00:00'}]},
  'data': [{'X': 572125,
   'Y': 6226875,
   'Data': [{'Time': '2023-07-10T00:00:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:01:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:02:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:03:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:04:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:05:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:06:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:07:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:08:00', 'Value': 0.399},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:09:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:10:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:11:00', 'Value': 0},
     ...
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T16:37:00', 'Value': 0.299},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T16:38:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T16:39:00', 'Value': 0},
     ...]},
   {'X': 572125,
   'Y': 6226875,
   'Data': [{'Time': '2023-07-10T00:00:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:01:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:02:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:03:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:04:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:05:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:06:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:07:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:08:00', 'Value': 0.399},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:09:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:10:00', 'Value': 0},
     ...
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T16:37:00', 'Value': 0.299},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T16:38:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T16:39:00', 'Value': 0},
     ...]},
   {'X': 571125,
   'Y': 6226125,
   'Data': [{'Time': '2023-07-10T00:00:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:01:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:02:00', 'Value': 0.259},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:03:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:04:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:05:00', 'Value': 0.321},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:06:00', 'Value': 0.279},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:07:00', 'Value': 0},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:08:00', 'Value': 0.371},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:09:00', 'Value': 0.399},
     {'Time': '2023-07-10T00:10:00', 'Value': 0.345},
     ...
```

So, I have in the beginning of my file, the `info` key that holds relevant information. The key `data` holds the information that I want to convert into a 3D grid. For each coordinate, there is time series instances as seen above, where I have included examples of 3 coordinate instances.

Comment: Please provide example data in the question itself

Comment: Sure, but I am not sure how. The data in the `json_object` is pretty large.

Comment: Do your `json_normalize`. Do not do your loop. You need to be more specific on what exactly you expect for a "3D grid". At least one interpretation is to `unstack()` so that your dataframe is 2D, but that does not work because X and Y are full of duplicates. How would you handle duplicates at X and Y? First value found? Average?

Comment: Hi @Reinderien, thanks for your comment. I guess the reason why there is duplicate X/Y-values is because there are values for each timestamp? I suppose there are n number of duplicates (timestamps). So there is n number of grids, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json_object["data"], record_path =["Data"],meta=["X","Y"])
```

is basically correct. You then ask:

> how do I turn this into a 3D grid?

Perhaps you mean a 2D array of values, but this is complicated by many factors, including that you have a lot of duplicates and there is irregular grid coverage in your data:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('json_data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)['data']

df = pd.json_normalize(data=data, record_path='Data', meta=['X', 'Y'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)

df = (
    df.set_index(['Y', 'X'])
    .Value.groupby(level=['Y', 'X'])
    .mean()
    .unstack(level='X')
)
```

[image: irregular grid]

If you actually want three indices (X/Y/Time), the same problems persist:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('json_data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)['data']

df = pd.json_normalize(data=data, record_path='Data', meta=['X', 'Y'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)

df = (
    df.set_index(['Y', 'X', 'Time'])
    .Value.groupby(level=['Y', 'X', 'Time'])
    .mean()
    .unstack(level='X')
)
```

[image: x y time]

Based on your comments, what you actually want is

- a frame where NaN are filled by zero;
- an outer index of Time, then Y;
- an inner (column) index of X; and
- duplicates eliminated by `first()`.

This means

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('json_data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)['data']

df = pd.json_normalize(data=data, record_path='Data', meta=['X', 'Y'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)

Z = (
    df.set_index(['Time', 'Y', 'X'])
    .Value.groupby(level=['Time', 'Y', 'X'])
    .first()
    .unstack(level='X', fill_value=0)
)
```

Don't loop.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. 
Well, I definitely mean a 2D grid with values  thanks! What do you mean by irregular grid?

Comment: Look at the first image. Your data are not defined over a consistent, rectangular range.

Comment: Give me an example. Because there is 250 m in between (dx/dy). However, I suppose I should say that NaN values can be replaced by 0’s.

Comment: Hi again. Perhaps my latest comment was a bit confusing.
So, I have been thinking. I have the dataframe with `X`, `Y` and `Time` attributes. I also have the number of timesteps with the JSON key `numt = data['info']['ProcessQuality'][0]['qualitySteps']`. Then I can make 3D grid (or 2D grid with values) by initiating `Z = np.zeros((numt,Numx,Numy))`. This gives me a grid with shape `(time,X,Y)`. Now, I understand this might be an irregular grid with missing values, but how do I map values corresponding to timestep, X and Y coordinates into this grid?

Comment: Take what I've written and add `fillna(0)`.

Comment: Can’t see how any of it can be turned into a grid? And why do you write `mean` after `groupby` method? Nothing should be averaged.

Comment: Remove it and see what happens. Like I've said, there are duplicate values; you need to decide how to collapse them.

Comment: Hi @Reinderien, I figured it out. So, my solution was to loop over the timestamps which is 3241 long. That is `timeStamps = [pd.to_datetime(t['Time']) for t in data['data'][0]['Data']]`. So here goes the loop where `;` indicates a new line: `for i, ts in enumerate(timeStamps): df_ts = df[df['Time']==ts]; df_grid = df_ts.set_index(['X','Y']).Value.groupby(level=['X','Y']).first().unstack(level='X'); Z[i] = df_grid.to_numpy()`. There I have my grid. I will accept your solution if you edit the response to what I just wrote (I did pick some of yours though ;))

Comment: @aloevgaard see edit. It's good that you've landed on what you want, but how you're getting it is non-advisable.

Comment: Well, I will accept it, but it is in my opinion that the bulletpoints you have written are a little bit wrong. Because I want a grid (same grid) for each timestamp, which is why you have to loop over each timestamp. If you do that, I can use your previous solution and avoid duplicate issues, because there is only one value for each coordinate instance. I have not stated that `NaN` values should be replaced by 0’s. I just initialize a `NumPy` array with 0’s.